# Does build made IOS 9 application runs on lower versions?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to learn IOS programming and I have searched and Find out that recently IOS 9 , Swift2 and Xcode 7 has been introduced and available . 
I was wondering the apps that are made inside Xcode 7 and IOS 9 can be run on Lower versions of IOS like IOS 8 ?
Because I want to buy  couple of Udemy courses that's about programming for ios 9 with Xcode 7 . But It's important to me that the apps that I'm going to make runs on lower version too .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, app build with Xcode 7 and iOS 9 SDK can run on iOS 8 and 7.
IN your apps project setting make sure to set the deployment version to 8 or 7.

But you will have to make sure yourself not to call methods of classes that are not are not available in the iOS version you have chosen as you deployment target. Calling methods or using classes not support by the iOS version will make your app crash.

Comment: Is it possible to check craches of apps on lower version of ios from simulator  ?

Comment: Of course, you can start your app on any of the support iOS version. So for Xcode 7 this is iOS 8.* & 9.*  But check the documentation or headers for the support iOS version is you think a method or class might not be supported.